# Android Wear : InsetActivity

Tags: android-activity, wear-os

I'm learning Android Wear and I'm confused with the Android Wear.
When I create the UI with a watchViewStub it works as expected. When I extend InsetActivity there is no library that knows this kind of object.
Checking on Android web site, there is no mention of InsetActivity.

So, where is the mistake? Is it an object that was on pre release and then not used by Android Wear, do I have to use a special library?

Answer (score 1):

InsetActivity is part of the wearable support library.
Ensure you have added the following dependency in your wear build.gradle.

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
```

Comment: It is in my wear build.gradle. My confusion is I cannot find any information in the android web site about this activity. on the following android web site https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/activity/WearableActivity.html they talk about WearableActivity and Confirmation Activity and I can use these activities without any problem. If I want information about InsetActivity, where do I have the information?

Comment: It would seem that InsetActivity is an alternative to using BoxInsetLayout and stubs and given the lack of documentation I'd look at the more commonly used approach for handling different layouts.